# Is Conan repository available in Artifactory OSS?

Tags: artifactory, conan

The webpage for JFrog's Artifactory OSS makes it seem like it's part of OSS https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/#conan. I'm trying it out in a Docker container and "Conan" doesn't show up as a clickable option in new local repository.

Am I misunderstanding what is the available in Artifactory OSS or did I set something up wrong?

Comment: As a side note, conan has an OSS server, called conan_server. It is not as feature-rich as Artifactory, but good enough for small and medium teams.

Comment: YAY! I think conan_server might be what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, conan repositories are not available in Artifactory OSS.
If in https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/, you go to "Artifactory OSS", then "Compare to PRO", you will see the full comparison matrix between them.

Comment: Thanks, I misread that. Artifactory OSS and Conan are open source but they don't work together without the price tag. I'm going to look into conan_server and Nexus Repository OSS. At Least Nexus has a free PyPi repository.

Comment: @loneraver Nexus (either free or paid) doesn't support Conan.

Comment: @loneraver that looking at Nexus won't solve the original question of finding a Conan repository.

Comment: @JBaruch, correct. Their product will not work for me as a stop shop. I'll have to have both Conan server and Nexus repository OSS installed.

Comment: Will you be able to correlate Conan artifacts with Python artifacts? Or you don't need to?

Comment: Also, do you think $85 a month is expensive for an universal repository?

Comment: @JBaruch, with all due respect, for a business, no. For personal projects and for state funded university, yes.

Comment: That's why I asked :) If those projects are open-source, feel free to [submit a request for a free Artifactory instance](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/#artifactory2).

Answer (score 7):

The [Artifactory community edition](https://jfrog.com/blog/announcing-jfrog-artifactory-community-edition-c-c/) for C/C++ is a new version of Artifactory offering free support for Conan repositories

Answer (score 0):

Conan repositories are not available in Artifactory OSS.  You need to pay for the Pro version.  For Nexus OSS, there is a plugin available.  We will be testing this in house shortly.

https://exchange.sonatype.com/details?extension=5596417057